# WARN Method initialized not implemented vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this error in OUTPUT window in visual studio code in version 1.13.1 and even after the new release 1.4 that error still exist any help please.

Comment: This may be caused by one of your extensions. Which section of the output window is the error in? Please try disabling your extensions to track down which one may be responsible

Comment: Thank you so much @MattBierner . I disabled all my extensions. I found that the error come out because of  JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense extension . you can put your comment as answer . thanks a gain